# ng-include and ngRoute: how to make them work together? (i.e. route to a view wihin a ng-include)

Tags: angularjs

[**EDITED**] My app has the following structure:

**index.html**

```
<body ng-app = "myApp" ng-controller ="mainController">
    <ng-view></ng-view>
</body>
```

**mainView.html** (loaded into ng-view through **routeProvider** in app.js)

```
<div ng-include src="subview1">
<div ng-include src="subview2">
```

**subview1** and **subview2** are set within **mainController** (mainView's controller) as scope variables:

```
$scope.subview1= "templates/subview1.html";
$scope.subview2= "templates/subview2.html";
```

**controller1** and **controller2** are **subview1** and **subview2**'s controllers.

**subview1.html** (loaded in first div of mainView)

```
 <div ng-controller="controller1">
    <button ng-click="loadNewView()"></button>
 </div>
```

**controller1.js**

```
.controller('controller1', function($scope){
     $scope.loadNewView = function(){
            $scope.$parent.subview1 = "templates/view3.html";
     }
}
```

**scope.loadNewView** should load a different view (and relative controller) within the div with **src="subview1"** in **mainView.html**). Basically it's about refreshing the view itself by raplacing it with another view (and related controller).

I use **$parent** to update the view in **subview1**'s parent view (i.e. **mainView**).

however nothing happens and if I try to use **$scope.$apply()** I get **error (digest already in progress)**.

Any clue?

Comment: I dont understand,on button click you want to load a new template with new controller in the same url.This is not the right way to do it,and i am also not sure if its possible,to do it dynamically.One approach would be to create one more url in your routeProvider and then use $location.path() or $location.url().

Comment: I just edited my question (there was same error in the code).
Basically when the user executes a particular action (e.g. click) on the current subview, I need that a new view is loaded over it (e.g. loginView --> userProfile view) it.
Can you please clarify by posting an answer your solution?

Comment: The only way and the right way to loadView and it's associated controller is creating a new route in $routeProvider and then on your button click call $location.path('/yourUrl') of the new view.

Comment: ok I now how to do it. but I'm afraid that will replace the whole container (mainContainer), not just subview1. Am I wrong?

Comment: ok, I found the solution. will post it below

Answer (score 3):

you can try something like this...
In your **stateProvider** or in your **routeProvider** if you using.

```
var mod = angular.module('example.states', ['ui.router']);

    mod.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
        function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
            $stateProvider
                .state('exampleState', {
                    url: '/main',
                    templateUrl: 'mainView.html',
                    controller: mainController
                });
        }
    ]);
    return mod;
```

So here you have associated your parent controller(let's say the mainController which will be the parent of all others) with its template mainView.html.

Then in your mainView.html,Load all the subview templates.

```
<div ng-repeat="template in templates">
                <ng-include src="template.url"></ng-include>             
            </div>
```

templates is an array in your mainController which has the url or path of all your subtemplates.When you use **ng-include** inside the main template then all subTemplates will automaticlly become the child of the mainTemplate and its Controllers too.In a way it will inherit from the parent Controller.

So suppose if **subView1.html** is one of the template url you had given in **ng-include**.Then it will look like

```
<div ng-controller="subView1Controller">
//Here your code
</div>
```

And subview2 as

```
<div ng-controller="subView2Controller">
    //Here your code
    </div>
```

This way you will have multiple views on the same page with one url and different controllers with its associated templates and each will inherit from the parent controller which is **mainController** here.

There, might be better approach than this.
This is what i had used in my project,and its simple to keep your code simple manage.

Comment: I use router provider.

Comment: I don't understand why your return mod and whether I should add the. Config in app.js where routing is defined.

Comment: Also, it's not clear to me how you actually load a new hire and why use ng repeat since I have only two subviews one of which is the one I want to reload I

Comment: You can use,routeProvider...and you dont have to use ng-repeat i just gave u an example,you can directly give src of your template in ng-include.

Comment: How and where you have defined controllers ?

Answer (score 1):

Okay,so using routeProvider,you can use it like this

```
var app = angular.module("app",[]);
  app.config(function($routeProvider){
      $routeProvider
      .when('/main',{
         templateUrl:"mainView.html",
         controller:mainController
       })
  });
  app.controller("mainController",function($scope){
  });
  app.controller("subView1Controller",function($scope){
  });
  app.controller("subView1Controller",function($scope){
  });
```

Then in your **mainView.html**,Load all the subview templates.

```
     <ng-include src="yoursubtemplate1path"></ng-include> 
 <ng-include src="yoursubtemplate2path"></ng-include>
```

And then in yoursubtemplate1 use

```
<div ng-controller="subView1Controller">
//Here your code
</div>
```

Same for the other templates.

You can set the template src of the subtemplates from your mainController.

```
 app.controller("mainController",function($scope){
$scope.templatesrc="/app/template1.html";
  });
```

And then use it in your template,where you are using ng-include directive.

```
<ng-include src="templatesrc"></ng-include>
```

Its better to store template url's in an array and use ng-repeat directive like i had stated before,if you are loading more templates.

And if you want to show the div on some button click lets say in parent controller then use **ng-if** in the sub-view main  and make it true on button click.

Comment: thank you very much for clarifying this.
could you just complete your answer by adding **how I change the src** from the controller of the subview itself?
(after that I will surely accept your answer :) )

Comment: set src for subView from the main controller.. okay,so you can do it by adding a $scope variable or say object in the mainController. eg:- $scope.template_src="/assets/subview1.html". Then bind it in the main view where you are using ng-include,as src="template_src".

Comment: thank you again. I tried your solution and works (partially).
Please check out my updated question

Answer (score 1):

This answer is regarding your updated question.

The solution which you had used before,will load all temlplate and once in **ng-include** and its associated controller making the mainController as parent.

But if you want to load a different view with its newController then you can try something like this.

Just add one more route and call on your event click,but remember this newView's Controller will have no parent-child relation with the mainView's controller.

```
var app = angular.module("app",[]);
  app.config(function($routeProvider){
      $routeProvider
      .when('/main',{
         templateUrl:"mainView.html",
         controller:mainController
       })
       .when('/anyName',{
         templateUrl:"templates/view3.html",
         controller:temp3Controller
       })
  });
```

And in your controller1.js

```
.controller('controller1', function($scope){
     $scope.loadNewView = function(){
            $location.path('/anyName');
     }
}
```

Inject location service in controller1.

Comment: but just for confirmation, this will replace the whole page (ng-view in index.html). right? in that case it's not what I want. before changing the application layout I was using $location indeed

Comment: you don't have to change your application layout,<ng-view> checks the url and loads its template and controllers associated with that url.Just add one more url as mentioned above which is '/anyName' and call it in $location.path('/anyName'). it will check the routeProvider with the given url and will load specific templates and controllers

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution.

The tricks is using

```
$scope.$parent.$parent.subview1 = "templates/view3.html";
```

instead of

```
$scope.$parent.subview1 = "templates/view3.html";
```

since, basically:

- ng-include is the child of mainView
- subview1 is the child of ng-include

Comment: I am not sure if it's a right way to do it. ng-include is a directive provided by angular it has nothing to do with any inhertance hierarchy with views.Basically here subView1 and subView2 inherits from mainView,that's the only relationship which exists in  here. If it's working fine then go ahead with it,but i will recommend you to think of a better approach.

Comment: thank you for your feedback.
how would you solve it without a workaround like this?

Comment: Why not just create a different view with different url  and call it using $location.path(),I had given answer regarding this. if there is a better approach you can come up with,then please share.