# How can I pre load a template in Angular UI router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using Angular UI router. I have many template calls like this:

```
var access = {
        name: 'access',
        templateUrl: 'app/access/partials/a1.html',
    };
```

The page served by Access depends on the :content.

Is there a way that I could combine all these HTML files into one and pre-load the files so every action didn't involve another request?  I realized I can put my HTML directly inside the template but can I combine the HTML from multiple templates into one file and have it all pre-loaded so it's ready when needed?

Comment: you could use `$templateCache` to putting this template

Comment: Yes you can combine them all that's why the "inline" templates have an ```id``` to be use. You could just have one file containing all your templates and include that or have them in the html index of your app. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache There is no need for any tools to achieve this, it's straight angularjs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29902322/ng-include-and-ngroute-how-to-make-them-work-together-i-e-route-to-a-view-wi/29902954#29902954 Have a look here... it might solve your problem..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Is there a way that I could combine all these HTML files into one and pre-load the files so every action didn't involve another request?

**Yes**, by using `html2js`;

or, to be exact, a grunt/gulp plugin called, respectively, [grunt-html2js](https://github.com/karlgoldstein/grunt-html2js) / [gulp-html2js](https://github.com/fraserxu/gulp-html2js)

---

HOW IT WORKS

### According to this [grunt-html2js tutorial](http://ng-learn.org/2014/08/Populating_template_cache_with_html2js/):

" `html2js` is a plugin (...) that parses all template files in your application and creates a javascript file that populates the [$templateCache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache).

This is very useful trick to reduce the number of request your app needs to make to start the application.

It can also minify the html snippets saving some bandwitdh as well."

### ----------

### According to the [grunt-html2s Github repository](https://github.com/karlgoldstein/grunt-html2js):

"`html2js` converts a group of templates to JavaScript and assembles them into an Angular module that primes the cache directly when the module is loaded.

You can concatenate this module with your main application code so that Angular does not need to make any additional server requests to initialize the application."

### ----------

### And according to me :)

What I like about `html2js` is that **you don't need to change any of your angular code**, but just configure `gruntfile.js` / `gulpfile.js`.

Your templateUrl files will then [automagically](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26618/what-is-the-purpose-of-using-the-word-automagically-when-we-already-have-auto) be available in `$templateCache`.

So it does exactly what you wished for:

- Combine all your templates into a module;
- Write the JavaScript source for the module;

All you need to do is to specify the module as a dependency in your code.

> Once the module is loaded, all your templates are available in the cache: no request needed!

---

EXAMPLES OF GRUNT / GULP CONFIG

```
grunt.initConfig({
  html2js: {
    options: {
    base: 'app',
    module: 'templates',
    htmlmin: {
      ... many available options: see GitHub repo ...
    }
  },
    main: {
      src: ['app/**/*.html'],
      dest: 'templates.js'
    },
  },
})
```

then just use the templates module as a dependency:

```
angular.module('myApp', [ 'templates']);
```

### ----------

Here is an example from the `gulp-html2js` GitHub repository:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  gulp.src('fixtures/*.html')
    .pipe(html2js({
      outputModuleName: 'template-test',
      useStrict: true
    }))
    .pipe(concat('template.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
})
```

---

TESTING

What's more, `html2js` is also a very good tool to [test directives that use the templateUrl property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214760/unit-testing-angularjs-directive-with-templateurl).

---

FOR MORE INFORMATION

I came accross `html2js` after reading [Joel Hooks](http://joelhooks.com/)' ([Egghead](https://egghead.io/) instructor) [book about automation](https://egghead.io/essential-angularjs-grunt-build), which I strongly recommend.

[Watch a dedicated video about `html2js` in the pro section](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-using-ng-html2js-to-convert-templates-into-javascript) of the EggHead website.

[Testing directives using the `templateUrl` property with `Karma` and `karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor`](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor)

---

NOTE

Technically, you could just use [ng-html2js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-html2js), without using Gulp or Grub; you could then use a command line like the following:

```
ng-html2js inputFile [outputFile] [-m moduleName] [--module-var ngModule]
```

However, as you would need to run the above command for each templateUrl file, Gulp/Grub automation seems to be a more efficient way to go.

---

DISCLAIMER

I have no particular interest or shares in the book/websites/tools I mentioned.

Note: I should also add, you also add this file to your html page:

```
 <script src="path/to/templates.js"></script>
```

Comment: great answer but as for gulp better solution would be `gulp-ng-html2js ` because `gulp-html2js` just make an array in `window` object that can not be used then as module dependency

Answer (score 5):

Why not use **ng-include** in your main html file to load all html's at once.

Something like this...

```
<div ng-repeat="template in templates">
                <ng-include src="template.url"></ng-include>             
            </div>
```

So here templates is an array of objects which contains all the url's the other templates which you want to load at once in your main.html file.

Answer (score 5):

Easy.  Create them all as [ng-template](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script) blocks:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="app/access/partials/a1.html">
    Content of the template.
</script>
```

Comment: I think this is what @gillesc was referring to.

Answer (score 2):

There is already a [grunt-angular-templates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-angular-templates) grunt plugin specific to this angular task only. i have been using it for a while now. this plugin automatically caches your HTML templates using `$templateCache` in one file which you can add in your application.

**grunt-angular-templates** - https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-angular-templates

Comment: How do I get ui-router to work with this? It seems that the routes I've defined don't work when the templates are only included in template cache. The route's 'templateURL' gets used instead and say it cannot find it.

Answer (score -1):

Use,

```
yourApp.run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.removeAll();    
}])
```

Your problem pointed in this site too,
http://javahow.net/questions/27321315/using-angulars-ui-router-how-can-we-make-sure-the-new-version-of-the-html-part