# Unable to access form of ng-include file $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I inspect `$scope` I see `firstForm` but I don't see `secondForm` in the object. I am at a loss as to why this is happening.

Here's the sandbox code:

***index.html***

```
<html ng-app>

    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var firstController = function ($scope){ };
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div ng-controller="firstController">
            <form name="firstForm"></form>
            <div ng-include="'second_form.html'"></div>
       </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

***second_form.html***

```
<form name="secondForm"></form>
```

Comment: `ng-include` will create another scope, so your form is on the child scope.

Comment: Might consider a simple directive to switch with `ng-include` that just has templatetUrl then won't have that child scope

Comment: define controller inside `ng-include` template would be good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @charlietfl for this suggestion:

> Might consider a simple directive to switch with ng-include that just has templatetUrl then won't have that child scope

***index.html***

```
<html ng-app="myModule">

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);

        myModule.directive('secondForm', function () {
            return{
                templateUrl: 'secondform.html'
            }
        });

        var firstController = function ($scope){
            console.log($scope);
        };

    </script>
</head>


<body>

    <div ng-controller="firstController">

        <form name="firstForm">
        </form>

        <div second-form></div>

    </div>

</body>
```

This works!

Answer (score 0):

`ng-include` will create another `$scope`.  If you want `firstController()` to handle both forms the do the following:

```
<div>
   <form ng-controller="firstController" name="firstForm"></form>
   <div ng-include="'second_form.html'"></div>
</div>
```

Then in `second_form.html` do:

`<form ng-controller="firstController" name="secondForm"></form>`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but in this particular case I cannot do that. The included file is being used somewhere else as well where `firstController` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

use other controllers in for **ng-include** directives.
In secondForm.html specify controller name as

```
<div ng-controller="secondCtrl">
</div>
```

So wen you use ng-inculde inside main controller all controllers of the subtemplates inside ng-include will inherit from the main controller,i.e it will have parent-child relationsship..

More more info go to this link

[ng-include and ngRoute: how to make them work together? (i.e. route to a view wihin a ng-include)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29902322/ng-include-and-ngroute-how-to-make-them-work-together-i-e-route-to-a-view-wi/29952679#29952679)